# How to obtain the identity in Entity Framework by using stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 database first approach. Now I am inserting data into the table and again returning the `IDENTITY`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAdmissonSlip_Insert]
(
    @paramStdClassID int,
    @paramFeeMonth varchar(20),
    @paramAdmissionFee int = null,
    @paramTutionFee int,
    @paramFeeSlip int = null,
    @paramResultFile int = null,
    @paramExamFee int = null,
    @paramSciCompFee int = null,
    @paramExtra int  =null
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into tblFee 
    values (@paramStdClassID, @paramFeeMonth, NULL, @paramAdmissionFee,
            @paramTutionFee, @paramFeeSlip, @paramResultFile,
            @paramExamFee, @paramSciCompFee, @paramExtra, 0);

    select @@IDENTITY;
END
```

My question is how to get this `IDENTITY` on front-end. Whether I should use the output parameter OR there is any different method to get this in `integer` type variable.

Here is the calling statement.

```
int FeeID = Convert.ToInt32 (OE.spAdmissonSlip_Insert(obj.StdClassID, obj.FeeMonth, obj.AdmissionFee, obj.TutionFee,
                            obj.FeeSlip, obj.ResultFile, obj.ExamFee, obj.SciCompFee, obj.Extra));
```

And this is the method definition..

```
 public ObjectResult<spAdmissonSlip_Insert_Result> spAdmissonSlip_Insert(Nullable<global::System.Int32> paramStdClassID, global::System.String paramFeeMonth, Nullable<global::System.Int32> paramAdmissionFee, Nullable<global::System.Int32> paramTutionFee, Nullable<global::System.Int32> paramFeeSlip, Nullable<global::System.Int32> paramResultFile, Nullable<global::System.Int32> paramExamFee, Nullable<global::System.Int32> paramSciCompFee, Nullable<global::System.Int32> paramExtra)
{
    ...
}
```

PS: I'm new to EF.

Comment: You already select the IDENTITY so EF should detect the return type of the procedure as an integer.

Comment: did you map you stored procedures to EF Model ?

Comment: @BassemAKl it is returning a column so EF has converted it into Complex type. What should I do now?

Comment: @Thomas sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: the complex type contains only an integer property which is mapped to @IDENTITY. You can access that property after calling the mapped method spAdmissonSlip_Insert().

Comment: @BassemAkl I have edited the post. please check it.. thank you

Comment: @AmmarBukhari, you can map your stored procedures to your model to insert delete update so that you don't need to face this kind of problem : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question about using output parameters or other method, I use `Scope_Identity()` in my applications and it works fine.

Change the line `select @@IDENTITY;` for:

```
SELECT Scope_Identity() AS Id
```

Check out the answer in this thread: [How to obtain the identity of an entity after calling SaveChanges() when the entity is mapped to stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731130/how-to-obtain-the-identity-of-an-entity-after-calling-savechanges-when-the-ent)

Let me know if you have any issues with this approch.